# clean up and filter log messages

Tags: bash, unix

I currently have a script which takes a file with the current month's worth of auditing data and outputs it to another folder with each day as a separate logfile.
However, I don't need every bit of every message to be outputted to these files.  The messages look like this:

```
01-07-2016 09:28:23:687|1200-{Context 0x1bf81010} {Id DM_SERVER} {Component ww42697_allow_me_sysadmin} {Table SYS_C_COMP} {Message {Executed 0:Ok} Chg Component: Component=AN_UST_LV_HousePricePublisher_FREE, FriSched=0000-1330, UpdatedBy=ww42697_allow_me_sysadmin} {Time 9282368} {Date 20160701} {TimeStamp 1467379703} {Record {Component AN_UST_LV_HousePricePublisher_FREE} {Enabled 1} {MonSched 0000-1730;1830-2400} {TueSched 0000-1730;1830-2400} {WedSched 0000-1730;1830-2400} {ThuSched 0000-1730;1830-2400} {FriSched 0000-1330} {SatSched } {SunSched 1830-2400} {Path /opt/mkvanalyticsnylnx/1.72_U0/bin} {Argv -classname com/citigroup/fi/analytics/usd/housepricepublisher/HousePricePublisher -appcf usd/app_rv.cf -jinit usd/HousePricePublisher.properties -log4jxml core/log4j.xml -gficfgname GTE -autocp 1 -log4jrolling 0 -pwpstop 1 -rv 1 -java -DRV_VERSION=8.2} {WorkDir /var/opt/} {DbDir } {LogsDir } {KillScript } {KillScriptArgv } {RestartIfNotReg 1} {RestartNums 5} {TimeoutKill 20} {TimeoutNotReg 60} {UpdatedBy ww42697_allow_me_sysadmin} {UpdatedInfo 0} {StopOnCrash 0} {EngineType 1} {Executable mkv_start7} {Version } {ScheduleTemplate } {CompleteExeName 0} {ComponentType } {DirtyFlag 0} {UpdId 420} } {SeqId 286414}
```

And a line with "Chg User":

```
01-07-2016 00:00:03:879|0638-{Context 0x1c316458} {Id DM_SERVER} {Component ar89576_PROD_SysAdmin} {Table SYS_C_USERS} {Message {Executed 0:Ok} Chg User: User=GTEApp, LastLoginTime=361} {Time 387} {Date 20160701} {TimeStamp 1467345603} {Record {UserID 149} {UserName GTEApp} {Password B0 C7 CC 83 FE CC D0 } {Type 2} {Passwdlen 21} {Auth 0} {AuthSource } {PasswdExt } {Disabled 0} {LoginMode 1} {DisablePasswdCheck 0} {PersonalInfo } {FailureCount 0} {LastLoginDate 20160701} {LastPwdChangeDate 0} {LastLoginTime 361} {CreationDate 0} {CreationTime 0} {LastEnableDate 0} {LinkedPolicy } {UpdatedBy ar89576_PROD_SysAdmin} {DirtyFlag 0} {UpdId 769760} } {SeqId 253929}
```

Additionally there are some lines which record the platform's initialization.  These are formatted differently and I don't need:

```
01-07-2016 00:00:03:879|0050-PSH::Config,ADD,ENT_REQTIMEOUT,60,3,NO DESCRIPTION
```

I only need lines outputted which contain the string "Chg Component" (some have "Chg User" instead), and I would like to get rid of the brackets around each field, seperated by a space or comma would be fine. I'd like only a few of the fields as well as per my example below:

```
01-07-2016 09:28:23:687,Component AN_UST_LV_HousePricePublisher_FREE,MonSched 0000-1730;1830-2400,TueSched 0000-1730;1830-2400,WedSched 0000-1730;1830-2400,ThuSched 0000-1730;1830-2400,FriSched 0000-1330,SatSched ,SunSched 1830-2400,Path /opt/mkvanalyticsnylnx/1.72_U0/bin,Argv -classname com/citigroup/fi/analytics/usd/housepricepublisher/HousePricePublisher -appcf usd/app_rv.cf -jinit usd/HousePricePublisher.properties -log4jxml core/log4j.xml -gficfgname GTE -autocp 1 -log4jrolling 0 -pwpstop 1 -rv 1 -java -DRV_VERSION=8.2,WorkDir /var/opt/,UpdatedBy ww42697_allow_me_sysadmin
```

The current script I have which is expected to output only the lines with "Chg Component" is only working for a small number of lines and a lot are not being outputted to the specified date files...

```
IN=/var/opt/MKV/platform15000/DM_SERVER/LOGS/AUDITING*
grep "Chg Component" $IN > /home/rg39523/AUDIT_BY_DATE/AUDIT_COMP_CHG.log

COMP_CHG=/home/rg39523/AUDIT_BY_DATE/AUDIT_COMP_CHG.log

exec < $COMP_CHG while read line do
    date=$(echo $line|cut -d" " -f 1)
    INTWO=/home/rg39523/AUDIT_BY_DATE/AUDITING.log.$date

    echo $line >> $INTWO done
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you used `exec <`, normally it is done using `cat file | while`, to remove the `{`, `}` I used just `tr`, assuming the fields don't contain those characters. Also I assume you don't want the original filename at the beginning of each line (added `-h` option to grep):

```
IN=/var/opt/MKV/platform15000/DM_SERVER/LOGS/AUDITING*
grep -h "Chg Component" $IN > /home/rg39523/AUDIT_BY_DATE/AUDIT_COMP_CHG.log

COMP_CHG=/home/rg39523/AUDIT_BY_DATE/AUDIT_COMP_CHG.log

cat $COMP_CHG | while read line do
    date=$(echo $line|cut -d" " -f 1)
    INTWO=/home/rg39523/AUDIT_BY_DATE/AUDITING.log.$date

    echo $line | tr -d {} >> $INTWO
done
```